# Flask Session Cookie not Saving?

Tags: flask

So what I have is a pretty basic Flask app with some user account login set-up. What I want to do is after posting to '/login', I want to redirect back to the home page where if my session cookie shows that I am logged in, it displays a different page. However, every time I redirect back to '/home', it brings me back to the login template. Any idea how to fix this? I should mention this isn't using Flask-Login, I have it set-up using a PyMongo db as a user database.

```
@route.app('/home')
  if 'username' in session:
    render_template('home.html')
  else:
    render_template('login.html')

@route.app('/login', methods=['POST'])
  users = mongo.db.users
  login = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})
  if login:
    if bcrypt.checkpw(request.form['password'], login['password']):
      session['username'] = request.form['username']
      redirect(url_for('home'))
  else:
    return "<h1>booo</h1>"
```

Comment: Do you use Flask-Login or have you created your own login logic? And please show the complete code. Otherwise it is impossible to help.

Comment: Using my own logic didn't think it would be relevant given the implementation and problem, but I'll update it real quick, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as an update, I'm not quite sure why `if 'username' in session:`
didn't work especially since it's used in another route elsewhere in the same file, but switching it to  `if not session.get('username') is None:` ended up working.

Comment: The correct would be    if 'username' in session.keys():